# NullPointerException con el findViewbyId

Tags: kotlin

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en kotlin. Me lanzó un error de null pointer exception en los findViewbyId.

```
 private fun setSizeBoard(){
       var iv: ImageView

       val display = windowManager.defaultDisplay
        val size = Point()
        display.getSize(size)
        val width = size.x

        var width_dp = (width / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)

        var lateralMarginsDP = 0
        val width_cell = (width_dp - lateralMarginsDP ) / 8
        val heigth_cell = width_cell

       for (i in 0..7){
           for(j in 0..7){

             //Error aquí
               iv = findViewById(resources.getIdentifier("c$i$j","id",packageName))

               var height = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,heigth_cell,getResources().getDisplayMetrics()).toInt()
               var width = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,width_cell,getResources().getDisplayMetrics()).toInt()

               iv.setLayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams(width,height))

           }
       }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema es simplemente que no estás definiendo una vista en la cual obtengas la referencia de alguno de sus elementos, debes definir de que vista deseas obtener la referencia del elemento, por ejemplo:

```
TextView myTextView;

public setView(view: View) {
  //Obtiene la referencia del TextView dentro de la vista View.
   myTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.my_textview)
}
```

por lo tanto, modifica tu función para que reciba la vista desde la cual deseas obtener la referencia de alguno de sus elementos.

```
 private fun setSizeBoard(view: View){
   
               ...
               ...
               ...
               //iv = findViewById(resources.getIdentifier("c$i$j","id",packageName))
               iv = view.findViewById(resources.getIdentifier("c$i$j","id",packageName))

               ...
               ...
               ...
           }
       }
    }
```